# transfer of pointer from function to function

Tags: c

I have a problem, because while loading data from the console, a bug is popping up I think it's a tricky thing to pass the indicator through the function, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct rn{
    int n;   /**numerator**/
    unsigned d;    /**denomirator**/
} rationalNumber;

typedef struct dot{
    rationalNumber x;
    rationalNumber y;
} point;

int gcd(int a, int b)
{
  if(b!=0)
    return gcd(b,a%b);

       return a;
}

void input(rationalNumber *a)
{
    int nwd;
    if (scanf("%d/%u",&(a->n), &(a->d)) == 1) a->d=1;
    else
    {
        nwd = abs(gcd(a->n, a->d));
        a->n = a->n/nwd;
        a->d = a->d/nwd;
    }


}

void load_point(point *a, void(*function)(rationalNumber *))
{
    function(&a->x);
    function(&a->y);

}

int main(void)
{

    rationalNumber *z;
    point *a;


    load_point(a, input);



return 0;
}
```

I've got this message : Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)

in this place : `if (scanf("%d/%u",&(a->n), &(a->d)) == 1) a->d=1;`

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Answer (score 2):

You're creating pointers that point to *nothing in particular* and then pass these on to the function which never initializes them, allocates memory for them, and trusts that they're valid, but they're not.

Remember that `point* a` is a pointer, not an allocation.

An easy solution is to use local variables instead of pointers:

```
int main(void)
{
    rationalNumber z;
    point a;

    load_point(&a, input);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: and a harder solution? Because this little change requires changing my whole code. Here, I just inserted a piece that doesn't work

Comment: @MarianKowal: The change in this answer does not require changing your whole code. Just make the changes shown in `main`.

Comment: It's deleting two characters, one if you account for the fact `rationalNumber* z` isn't used so that's irrelevant.

Comment: @tadman I think he needs to modify his load_point function since you are already passing an address to it. Not that his original function would have worked as he intended.

Comment: @luci88filter The function already wants `point* a` which is exactly what this will give.

Comment: @tadman Yes, you are right, I misread what he meant in the function. Sorry.